# How do I download a web page and export to PDF using python

Tags: python, pdf

I am trying to figure out how I can give python a list of urls and have it create a pdf for that url. So step one/part one of the question is (how to suck up all the contents including images, etc). and step 2 would be how do I push that content to a pdf.  I can figure out step 3 which is the joining of pdfs.

I've found this: [http://svn.python.org/view/*checkout*/python/trunk/Tools/webchecker/websucker.py?content-type=text%2Fplain](http://svn.python.org/view/%2acheckout%2a/python/trunk/Tools/webchecker/websucker.py?content-type=text%2Fplain) but don't know if it helps as a solution.

Also, I'm aware of urllib, but it does not get images/etc that I would like to have in the pdf.

Thanks : )

If it helps to think of an application, say I have a folder full of bookmarks for cooking recipes and I want to make a personal cookbook out of it.  Kinda what I'm going for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need the links to be 'live', you can take 'snapshots' of all of the webpages of interest using [khtml2png](http://khtml2png.sourceforge.net/) (linux) or [webkit2png](http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/) (mac), although you will just get images of the websites this way.. and then [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/index.htm) can convert the images to PDFs.

Comment: sounds like a neat idea, I'll give that a shot.